# Flex 3, 4 and 4.5 Components and Containers

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, comparison, flex4.5

This [page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex3and4_differences.html) has tables about ***Flex 3 MX components and their Flex 4 Spark counterparts*** as well as ***Flex 3 classes with no direct Flex 4 counterpart***. Could anyone share the same for Flex 4 and Flex 4.5? The nearest I can find is ***New Spark components in Flex 4.5 SDK*** at page [Introducing Adobe Flex 4.5 SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/introducing-flex45sdk.html) but not in table form. Comparing 3 versions side by side in table form is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flex 4; Adobe introduced a new architecture for building components.  This architecture was designed to help make skinning and styling easier.  It introduced a two class architecture, separating the business logic from the display logic.

The page you link to is really comparing the MX/Halo architecture components with the Spark architecture components.  More info on the [architecture differences](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS92a952957940f5c1611f737312188328b93-8000.html).

It is important to keep in mind that the MX/Halo architecture did not go away.  It still exists in Flex 4 and can be used in conjunction with Spark components.

I would have sworn there was an explicit table somewhere in the docs talking about component differences between spark and Halo, but I can't find it.  The best I can recommend to you is to read through this [section of the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc3ff6d0ea7785946679bc22e1208826805f-8000.html).